# How can I open a new tab with Gtkmm?

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I created a notebook with the library gtkmm but I can't open some new tabs. This is my code :

There is three file :

main.cpp

```
#include <gtkmm/main.h>
#include "win.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
Win win;
Gtk::Main::run(win);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

win.hpp :

```
#ifndef DEF_WIN
#define DEF_WIN

#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

class Win : public Gtk::Window{
public:
Win();
private:
Gtk::Notebook m_notebook;
Gtk::Grid m_grid1;
Gtk::Grid m_grid2;
};
#endif
```

And this is the last file :

```
#include "win.hpp"


Win::Win(){


    maximize();
    set_title("Test");


    Gtk::VBox *boxV = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::VBox(false,0));
    add(*boxV);


    Gtk::MenuBar *barreMenu = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuBar);
    boxV->pack_start(*barreMenu, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    Gtk::MenuItem *menuItemFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("_File",true));
    barreMenu->append(*menuItemFile);
    Gtk::Menu *menuFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
    menuItemFile->set_submenu(*menuFile);
    Gtk::ImageMenuItem *menuNew = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ImageMenuItem(Gtk::Stock::NEW));
    menuFile->append(*menuNew);
    menuNew->signal_activate().connect([this]() {
m_notebook.append_page(m_grid1,"Hello");
        });




    m_notebook.popup_enable();



    Gtk::Grid* grid1 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Grid());


    grid1->set_border_width(0);
    grid1->set_row_spacing(0);

    Gtk::Label *title = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Label());
    title->set_markup("<b><span size='xx-large'>Welcome !");
    title->set_hexpand(true);
    grid1->attach(*title,0,0,10,1);





    Gtk::Button *commencer = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Button("Start"));
    grid1->attach(*commencer,4,7,2,3);
    commencer->set_hexpand(true);   
    commencer->signal_clicked().connect([this]() {
    m_notebook.append_page(m_grid2,"Hey");
    });


    m_notebook.append_page(*grid1, "New worksheet");
    boxV->pack_start(m_notebook);


show_all();
}
```

The code compiles without any problems. But when I execute the code and click on Start or New I get no new tabs and I don't know why because I put into the signal this:

```
m_notebook.append_page(m_grid1,"Hello");
```

and also this:

```
 m_notebook.append_page(m_grid2,"Hey");
```

Answer (score 0):

Each widget needs to be [shown](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#aa791d86a0bb3658e378e81d731dd0121) after creation.

`*grid1` is shown with `window.show_all()` but at the moment of execution of that method `m_grid1` and `m_grid2` have no parent and are not in `window`'s hierarchy.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto Application = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.maximize();
    window.set_title("Test");

    Gtk::Grid m_grid1, m_grid2;

    Gtk::VBox *boxV = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::VBox(false,0));
    window.add(*boxV);

    Gtk::MenuBar *barreMenu = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuBar);
    boxV->pack_start(*barreMenu, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    Gtk::MenuItem *menuItemFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("_File",true));
    barreMenu->append(*menuItemFile);
    Gtk::Menu *menuFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
    menuItemFile->set_submenu(*menuFile);
    Gtk::ImageMenuItem *menuNew = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ImageMenuItem(Gtk::Stock::NEW));
    menuFile->append(*menuNew);

    Gtk::Notebook m_notebook;
    menuNew->signal_activate().connect([&]() {
            m_notebook.append_page(m_grid1,"Hello");
            m_grid1.show();
        });

    m_notebook.popup_enable();

    Gtk::Grid* grid1 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Grid());

    grid1->set_border_width(0);
    grid1->set_row_spacing(0);

    Gtk::Label *title = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Label());
    title->set_markup("<b><span size='xx-large'>Welcome !</span></b>");
    title->set_hexpand(true);
    grid1->attach(*title,0,0,10,1);

    Gtk::Button *commencer = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Button("Start"));
    grid1->attach(*commencer,4,7,2,3);
    commencer->set_hexpand(true);   
    commencer->signal_clicked().connect([&]{
            m_notebook.append_page(m_grid2,"Hey");
            m_grid2.show();
        });

    m_notebook.append_page(*grid1, "New worksheet");
    boxV->pack_start(m_notebook);

    window.show_all();

    Application->run(window);
    return 0;
}
```

Also I suspect you want to create new grid every time the button is clicked. Now your code adds the same grid multiple times.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto Application = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.maximize();
    window.set_title("Test");

    Gtk::Grid m_grid1, m_grid2;
    Gtk::Notebook m_notebook;

    auto addGrid = [&]{
        Gtk::Grid* grid1 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Grid());
        Gtk::Label *title = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Label("Welcome 2"));
        grid1->attach(*title,0,0,10,1);
        m_notebook.append_page(*grid1,"Hello");
        grid1->show();
    };

    Gtk::VBox *boxV = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::VBox(false,0));
    window.add(*boxV);

    Gtk::MenuBar *barreMenu = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuBar);
    boxV->pack_start(*barreMenu, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    Gtk::MenuItem *menuItemFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("_File",true));
    barreMenu->append(*menuItemFile);
    Gtk::Menu *menuFile = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
    menuItemFile->set_submenu(*menuFile);
    Gtk::ImageMenuItem *menuNew = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ImageMenuItem(Gtk::Stock::NEW));
    menuFile->append(*menuNew);

    menuNew->signal_activate().connect(addGrid);

    m_notebook.popup_enable();

    m_grid1.set_border_width(0);
    m_grid1.set_row_spacing(0);

    Gtk::Label *title = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Label());
    title->set_markup("<b><span size='xx-large'>Welcome !</span></b>");
    title->set_hexpand(true);
    m_grid1.attach(*title,0,0,10,1);

    Gtk::Button *commencer = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Button("Start"));
    m_grid1.attach(*commencer,4,7,2,3);
    commencer->set_hexpand(true);   
    commencer->signal_clicked().connect(addGrid);

    m_notebook.append_page(m_grid1, "New worksheet");
    boxV->pack_start(m_notebook);

    window.show_all();

    Application->run(window);
    return 0;
}
```